# How to change admob app id remotely in android manifest?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, admob, ads

I Integrate AdMob remotely in Flutter, but it is difficult to change the Android manifest programmatically when it comes to the app id.
I was just wondering if I could control `ADMOB_APP_ID`:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Or initialize AdMob SDK without using the meta-data above.

Trying to control Ad units remotely without having control of the app id is useless.
Is there anyone that can help with this?

Comment: 1 - NO, You CANNOT CONTROL ADMOB_APP_ID by code as it's parsed at compiled time (The manifest get's parsed at compile time) and all metadata inside of it remains static data.  2- "Trying to control Ad units remotely without having control of the app id is useless" what do you mean exactly with that, what do you intend "remotely" exactly??

Comment: I mean by that, let's you have an app that has admob ads and for some reason the admob account got suspended, if we have control on the app id we can store the app id and unit ids in a json file hosted somewhere and we get the ids by an http get request. This way if the admob suspended we can easily change the ids from another admob account for example and we won't be forced to update the app on google play so wee keep running the ads on the app.

Comment: That is not possible, but even it was something easy to do (technically meaning) my advice is: don’t do it, you might be radiated forever by AdMob program.